# Help with Register File Implementation on Logisim

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture, processor, mips, register-file

[image]I'm currently working on an assignment that involves implementing a register file with 2 read ports and 1 write port on Logisim. I've made some progress but I'm struggling with a few questions and could use some help.

**Firstly**, I'm trying to understand if the read operation, the write operation, or both operations are clocked and why it is implemented this way. From my understanding, the write operation is clocked, meaning the write enable signal is updated on the clock edge. However, the read operation is not clocked, meaning the read ports can be updated asynchronously. I'm not entirely sure why this is done, so any insights would be appreciated.

**Secondly**, I need to explain the semantics of reading from and writing to $0 and how I implemented this behavior. As per my understanding, reading from $0 always returns the value zero, and writing to $0 is ignored. To implement this, I've used a multiplexer for the write input of $0 that always selects the value zero, and I ignore any write enable signal for $0. However, I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, so any feedback would be helpful.

**Lastly**, I need to determine how many bits of data this register file can store and how many bits it would store if the address width was the same size as for a complete 32-bits MIPS processor. Based on my calculations, this register file can store 8 registers, each of 32 bits, so it can store 8x32=256 bits of data. If the address width was the same size as for a complete 32-bits MIPS processor, the register file would store 2^5 x 32 = 1024 bits of data. I just want to confirm if my calculations are correct.

Here's a picture of my circuit on Logisim:

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: For your first question, just think about the larger context of usage and the clocked pipeline stages. Is it possible that the read results can be asynchronous since their output (input to the next stage) will be taken at the next clock edge when it is guaranteed they are stable?

Comment: Seems like you got it right. Only thing I don't get is why register 0 needs to be an actual register instead of just hard-wiring 00000000 to the read ports. (Then register 0 is not "stored" and wouldn't count in the last question)